# Angular: Is it possible to switch off offline support and use only swUpdate service for ServiceWorkers?

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

**service workers** are installed with standard schematics:

```
ng add @angular/pwa
```

Is it possible to switch off **offline** support, to use only **SwUpdate** service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable Angular Service Worker from serving all or some resources from cache by specifying your custom "navigationUrls" in ngsw-config.json. For example

```
"navigationUrls": []
```

[Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#matching-navigation-request-urls)

I also noticed that in that case you have to trigger checkForUpdate() method explicitly (for example, on the app init or [with some cadence](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications#checking-for-updates))